# ¿Cómo borrar valores de celdas específicas al terminar de escribir un valor en otra?

Tags: excel, vba

Me propuse hacer un excel para automatizar un proceso matemático y me surgió este problema:

Tengo 4 opciones (mostradas abajo), las cuales tienen celdas simulando textbox. Al presionar el botón de "Activar Filtro" tiene que modificar ciertos valores en una tabla de una hoja ajena. El problema es que solo puede haber un "textbox" con valor. Podría mandar un mensaje de error, diciéndole al usuario que borre las celdas que no quiere y deje solo una con valor, pero quiero mejor aprender a borrar los valores de las celdas ajenas a la última escrita de las 4.

[image: Formulario que quiero programar]

Me manejo más o menos con macros y no con vba, por lo que no quise pedir que me hicieran el código y quise avanzarlo para preguntar en caso de que me surgiera un error... y bueno, acá me surge un error. Error '-2147417848 (80010108)'.

[image: Error '-2147417848 (80010108)']

Y este código es lo que pude hacer investigando con Google.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim CeldasClaves As Range
Dim CeldaActiva As String
Dim TextBoxs(4) As String

TextBoxs(1) = "$C$2"
TextBoxs(2) = "$C$4"
TextBoxs(3) = "$C$6"
TextBoxs(4) = "$C$8"

' Defino las 4 celdas que deben accionar el evento, pasado por parámetro
Set CeldasClaves = Range("C2,C4,C6,C8")
CeldaActiva = ActiveCell.Address

'Esta línea está sacada de Internet y funciona
  If Not Application.Intersect(CeldasClaves, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

'Intento borrar las otras celdas cuando son distintas a la celda activa
    For i = 1 To 4
        If TextBoxs(i) <> CeldaActiva Then
            Range(TextBoxs(i)).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i

  End If
End Sub
```

Agradecería que me ayudaran o bien explicándome el modivo del error o cambiando el código, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Depúralo con F8. ¿Se ejecuta el bucle al menos 1 vez o falla a la primera?

Comment: Como quieres que se eliminen los otros campos que no se van a enviar? Al escribir en otro campo quieres que se vayan borrando el resto?